# Type of my class in dictionary in Spring.net

Tags: c#, dictionary, spring.net

I have an application that use Spring.net.
I want to create a dictionary instance.
The key type is "string".
The value type is "IToolsetModel" (interface that I wrote).
The assembly file of my interface is "ElmoMotionControl.Activity.Model" and the namespace is
"ElmoMotionControl.Activity.Model.ToolsetModel" (Same as the assembly).
In the springs xml I wrote:

```
<object id ="SystemConfigActivityDictionary" type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;string,ElmoMotionControl.Activity.Model.ToolsetModel.IToolsetModel>">
 <constructor-arg>
  <dictionary key-type="string" value-type="ElmoMotionControl.Activity.Model.Toolset.IToolsetModel, ElmoMotionControl.Activity.Model">
    <entry key="SystemConfigActivityToolset" value-ref="SystemConfigActivityToolset"/>
  </dictionary>
</constructor-arg>
```

I get Error: "Could not load type from string value 'ElmoMotionControl.Activity.Model.IToolsetModel'."

What I miss?

Thanks alot

Comment: I solved my problem. Thanks. The problem was that you can't use ref-value of object that placed after current object.

Comment: Please answer your question and accept your own answer; that way everybody knows your problem was solved.